# Prolog Scheduling Project

Tags: prolog, scheduling

i am working on a small project that schedules TAs workload and most of the predicates i have done are working except the final one which is weekschedule which takes :-
1-2d list with the tut numbers in each slot
2-1d list with the ta names and load
3-the maximum number of slots a TA can take per day
4-the result(2d list(week schedule)).
here is an example:-?-

```
week_schedule([[1, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 2, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 2, 1, 1, 0] ,
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ],
[ta(k, 8), ta(m, 4), ta(n, 3)],
3,
WeekSched).
WeekSched = [ [[k], [k], [k,m], [m], []],
[[], [], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [], []],
[[], [k,n], [], [], []],
[[], [k,n], [k], [n], []],
[[m], [], [k], [k], [m]]
];
```

this is my code and it always return false

```
ta_slot_assignment([ta(H1,Load)|T],[ta(H1,L)|T],H1):-!,Load>0,L is Load-1 .
ta_slot_assignment([H|T],[H|T2],Z):-ta_slot_assignment(T,T2,Z).
ta_slot_assignment([],[],_).

permutation_without_duplicates(X, R) :-permutation_helper(X, [], R).

permutation_helper([], X, X).
permutation_helper([H|T], Acc, R) :- \+ member(H, Acc),permutation_helper(T, [H|Acc], R).
permutation_helper([H|T], Acc, R) :-member(H, Acc),permutation_helper(T, Acc, R).
    
slot_assignment(0,X,X,[]).
slot_assignment(LabsNum,X,[H2|T2],[H|R]):- permutation_without_duplicates(X,Y),L is LabsNum-1,ta_slot_assignment(Y,[H2|T],H),slot_assignment(L,T,T2,R).
slot_assignment(LabsNum,X,[H2|T2],[H|R]):- L is LabsNum-1,ta_slot_assignment(X,[H2|T],H),slot_assignment(L,T,T2,R).
max_slots_per_day([],_).
max_slots_per_day([H|T],Max):-flatten([H|T],[H2|T2]),helper(H2,T2,1,Max),max_slots_per_day(T2,Max).

helper([],_,_,_).
helper(_,[],_,_).
helper(X,[X|T],Acc,Max):-!,A is Acc+1,A=<Max,helper(X,T,A,Max).
helper(X,[_|T],Acc,Max):-Acc=<Max,helper(X,T,Acc,Max).

day_schedule([],X,X,[]).
day_schedule([H|T],TAs,Y,[H1|T1]):- slot_assignment(H,TAs,Z,H1),day_schedule(T,Z,Y,T1),max_slots_per_day([H1|T1],3).


week_schedule([],_,_,[]).
week_schedule([H|T],TAs,DayMax,[Day|T1]):-day_schedule(H,TAs,Rem,Day),week_schedule(T,Rem,DayMax,T1).
```

Comment: Consider [this](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/timetabling/).